# Do not understand how to route to different ports on same ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

I currently have an autoscaling group that was launched by my cloudformation template. It currently has one instance. This instance has an application running on port 8080, and another one running on port 5005. I have an ALB in a separate stack. I would like to be able to type in the ip address of the ec2 instance followed by the port number in the browser and have the appropriate application open up. For instance, typing xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 in the browser currently opens up that first application no problem. I want the same result for the application on port 5005.

As I said before, my ALB exists in a separate stack than my autoscaling group. In the same stack as my autoscaling group, I have a target group with protocol HTTP with port 8080. I also have an HTTPS Listener with port 443 that redirects from the ALB, which has a custom DNS name, to the target group.

How can I achieve the functionality involving typing in xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5005 to open the appropriate application?

Comment: Why do you want users to type in a specific IP address? This will not work if the instance fails and is replaced, nor will it work if more than one instance is launched in the Auto Scaling group.

Comment: I actually do have a nice DNS name for my load balancer so that the user does not have to type in an IP. I was just going in baby steps trying to get the IP method working first and then trying to get it so they type in the nice DNS name followed by a port or a specific address to get the specified app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal method is:

- Create two **Target Groups** in the Load Balancer: One for each app
- Create a friendly **DNS name** for the Load Balancer (eg `example.com`) using Route 53
- Configure an **Application Load Balancer** to redirect to the appropriate Target Group based upon a URL rule (eg `example.com/app1/` and `example.com/app2/`)
- Configure the **Auto Scaling group** to register instances with the Load Balancer

This way, whenever the Auto Scaling group adds/removes instances, the Target Groups will be updated. Users simply go to a normal URL and they are redirected to one of the instances on the appropriate port.

Comment: Would I need to add anything to my HTTPS listener?

Comment: You would configure rules on your Listeners to determine which Target Group should receive the message. See: [Listeners for Your Application Load Balancers - Elastic Load Balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html)